# How Can I Access `struct` 's Field in a New `type` of That `struct` slice?

Tags: go, struct, types

The codes are like these

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Hello struct {
    ID  int
    Raw string
}

type World []*Hello

func HelloWorld() *World {
    return &World{
        {
            ID:  1,
            Raw: "asd",
        },
        {
            ID:  2,
            Raw: "jkf",
        },
    }
}

func main() {
    something := HelloWorld()

    // What I want to achieve...
    fmt.Println(something[0].Raw) // This should return `"asd"`.
}
```

But I got this error ---> `./prog.go:29:23: invalid operation: something[0] (type *World does not support indexing)`. How can I get `Raw` from `something`?

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `(*something)[0].Raw` because `something` is a pointer of `World` type.

We need to use * operator, also called dereferencing operator which if placed before a pointer variable and it returns the data in that memory.

```
fmt.Println((*something)[0].Raw)
```

Comment: Oh newbie mistake sorry :( . I will accept your answer ASAP.